# What is App_Browser Folder and why it caused to Bug?

Tags: asp.net, css, iis, deployment, menu

I have a website in which I used [CSSFriendly](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/). [CSSFriendly](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/) convert Asp.net Menu to UL-LI items.

When I Add [CssFriendly](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/) Project to my solution and build it, it add

- 1 App_Browser folder to my Website
- 1 DLL (with pdb) in BIN
- 1 __browserCapabilitiesCompiler.compiled in BIN

files

I'm wondered that everything is OK in my IIS. but when I upload it to my host it caused to a bug. when I removed `__browserCapabilitiesCompiler.compiled` from `bin` and also delete `App_Browser` from the root, problem resolves and website displayed. But unfortunately [CSSFriendly](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/) don't work at all.

So what's the matter and how can I resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your application to send the correct XHTML-conformant markup to the validation service by creating a browser definition for the validation service's user agent string.

For example, the W3C Markup Validation Service reports a user agent that begins with "W3C_Validator". To create a browser definition for the W3C validator, you can create a .browser file in your application's App_Browsers folder (you can name the .browsers file anything you like) and then add the following browsers element.

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc57y7e.aspx) for more information

This doesn't give you a direct answer, but the information on that page may help you solve your problem.